# by_row vs rowwise iteration

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Does anyone know what the difference is between `by_row`, and `rowwise`? I am trying to scrape 3 simple websites, and I can't seem to get either approach to work, so I'm not sure if I am just using `purr`/`dplyr` wrong.

Data:

```
structure(list(beer_brewerid = c("8481", "3228", "10325"), link = 
c("https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/8481/",  "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3228/", "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/10325/" ), scrapedname = c("", "", "")), .Names = c("beer_brewerid",  "link", "scrapedname"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

For every URL(or row), I would like to scrape the webpage using the following function:

```
dplyr approach:
    table %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      read_html() %>%
      extract2(2) %>%
      html_nodes("#_brand4 span") %>%
      html_text()
```

Purr Approach:

```
#Apply function to each row
table %>%
  by_row(..f = parserows(), collate = c("rows"), .to = "scrapedname")

#Takes in row 
parserows = function(){
      read_html() %>%
      extract2(., 2) %>%
      html_nodes("#_brand4 span") %>%
      html_text()
}
```

In the `purr` approach I keep getting an error where x is missing with no default. Shouldn't the value be coming from the row number? Otherwise I'd be writing a for loop specifying what index the row number is located at.

Using this magrittr piping, I keep getting timeout errors with my code.So:

1. How do I avoid timeout errors when using purr/dplyr to iterate over all the elements in my df? If so, should I be looking at using `trycatch`, or some sort of error handling mechanism to capture errors when they occur?
2. Is rowwise/ by_row really meant for this task? I think these functions are meant to iterative over every element within a row, which is not exactly what I am trying to solve with this problem at hand. Thanks.

   ```
   output = table$link %>%
   extract() %>%
   map(read_html) %>%
   html_nodes(row,"#_brand4 span") %>%
   html_text(row)
   ```

Comment: I'd treat your links as a vector and map over them: `my_dat$link %>%
  map(read_html) %>% ... `

Comment: Only problem is that when I have lots of links I want to scrape, I keep getting timeout errors. See updated code.

Comment: Take a look at `purrr::safely` and `purrr::transpose`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what @Thomas K's suggestions could look like:

First with `purrr` only:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

table$link %>%
  purrr::set_names() %>% 
  map(read_html) %>%
  map(html_node, "#_brand4 span") %>%
  map(html_text)

# $`https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/8481/`
# [1] "Föroya Bjór"
# 
# $`https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3228/`
# [1] "King Brewing Company"
# 
# $`https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/10325/`
# [1] "Bavik-De Brabandere"
```

(Note there is no need to use `html_nodes` (plural), rather than `html_node` (singular)).

A mixed `dplyr`/`purrr` alternative, which lets you keep each html doc in a tidy dataframe, if you need to reuse them:

```
res <-
  table %>% 
  mutate(html = map(link, read_html),
         brand_node = map(html, html_node, "#_brand4 span"),
         scrapedname = map_chr(brand_node, html_text))
```

The `html` and `brand_node` columns are stored as external pointers and are not very print-friendly, so here is the resulting dataframe without them:

```
select(res, - html, - brand_node)

#   beer_brewerid                                 link          scrapedname
# 1          8481  https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/8481/          Föroya Bjór
# 2          3228  https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3228/ King Brewing Company
# 3         10325 https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/10325/  Bavik-De Brabandere

glimpse(res)

# Observations: 3
# Variables: 5
# $ beer_brewerid <chr> "8481", "3228", "10325"
# $ link          <chr> "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/8481/", "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3228/", "https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/10325/"
# $ scrapedname   <chr> "Föroya Bjór", "King Brewing Company", "Bavik-De Brabandere"
# $ html          <list> [<html lang="en">, <html lang="en">, <html lang="en">]
# $ brand_node    <list> [<span itemprop="name">, <span itemprop="name">, <span itemprop="name">]
```

For the timeout issue, you could, also per @Thomas K's comment, simply wrap `read_html` in `safely()` or `possibly()` (which are indeed alternatives to `tryCatch`):

```
safe_read_html <- possibly(read_html, otherwise = read_html("<html></html>"))
```

But to address the (possible) real issue that you're going too hard on the server, I would suggest `httr::RETRY()` that lets you, well, retry, with "exponential backoff times":

```
safe_retry_read_html <- possibly(~ read_html(RETRY("GET", url = .x)), otherwise = read_html("<html></html>"))
```

A good practice when scraping is to go real gentle on the server, so you could even manually add an offset time before each request, with `Sys.sleep(1 + runif(1))` for instance.

```
table$link %>%
  c("https://www.wrong-url.foobar") %>% 
  purrr::set_names() %>% 
  map(~ {
    Sys.sleep(1 + runif(1))
    safe_retry_read_html(.x)
  }) %>%
  map(html_node, "#_brand4 span") %>%
  map_chr(html_text)

#  https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/8481/  https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3228/ 
#                        "Föroya Bjór"               "King Brewing Company" 
# https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/10325/         https://www.wrong-url.foobar 
#                "Bavik-De Brabandere"                                   NA
```

Lastly, there is your separate question about `by_row()`/`rowwise()`.
First, note that `by_row` has been removed from the development version of `purrr`, and moved to a separate package, `purrrlyr`, where it's deprecated anyway, and it's recommended to "use a combination of: `tidyr::nest()`; `dplyr::mutate()`; `purrr::map()`"

From `help("rowwise")`, `rowwise` is mostly meant to be "used for the results of `do()` when you create list-variables".

So, no, neither is "really meant for this task", they would be superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation, as I realized earlier that rowwise is not exactly what I wanted to do lol. I saw some solutions that use possibly, but it looked somewhat sketchy. I have about 7,000 urls I need to go through, so this this is very helpfull.

Comment: Should you be chaining together multiple map commands using the magrittr pipe? I really like the idea of using map with the pipe, but I'm a bit unsure what the ~{ } are doing with the map command

Comment: You could either chain `map()`s like I did, or put everything in one. It's a matter of taste I guess. For the meaning of the tilde `~`, see `purrr` vignettes for instance. It's essentially an abbreviated anonymous function through the versatile formula notation

Comment: for completeness, this code is much easier to understand, but not as verbose as your answer:
`getBrewerName <- function(df){
   possibly(df$scrapedname <- 
    df %>%
    extract2("link") %>%
    map(read_html) %>%
    map(html_nodes, xpath = '//*[(@id = "_brand4")]//span') %>%
    map(html_text) %>%
    unlist
, NA)
}`